# Marketing Cloud Data Relationships - what kind of joins are created?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

To be honest, I've never messed with Data Relationships before.  I've always used SQL queries to segment my data.  So, with Data Relationships, my assumption is that a SQL query is generated on the back end to bring back the resulting data.  When using a Data Relationship, we're able to join two tables together by primary key.  Is this "join" implied as an "inner join"?  Or what does this really look like on the back end?

Answer (score 3):

we told support we had same problem.

This was their answer:

After further investigation, I can confirm that the reason the number of records is returned is lower with the OR is because Data Filters use INNER JOINS.

This means that all the records need to exist in all of the the Data Extensions that are being used for the filter criteria.

I've received confirmation internally that this is how Data Filters with the use of Data Relationships are designed and it is not possible to change this behaviour.

"this makes OR operator unuseful", was my reply.